# Why don't we find the analytical function of the cost function?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

Then we could derive it and find minimum(s). e.g. in small networks the cost function has not so many variables.

Comment: In some sense, we do. When we have a neural network with no hidden layers and no activation functions, we have an easy equation for the parameters. That case is linear regression, which, yes, really is a neural network with no hidden layers and no activation functions.

Comment: and with lets say one hidden layer?

Comment: For a linear regression, you can simply minimise the SSR using matrix algebra by $(X'X)^{-1} X'y = \beta$. However, for more "complex" situations you need to resort to gradient descent or a maximum likelyhood estimation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on the question? What is your proposal to find the minima for let's say 2 layers of 5 Neurons with Sigmoid activation

Answer (score 2):

The power of networks come from hidden layers with non-linear activation functions. Said **non-linear activation function make the calculation of an analytical solution impossible** (except maybe for some very specific cases that are not really usefull).

If you need more convincing look at logistic regression : **a one-neuron network with sigmoid activation which does not have an analytical solution**.

As to why there is no closed form solution, you need to understand that the **linear regression you gave in exemple is a very simple problem of projecting a 'point' on a 'plane'**. Using an activation function on one neuron is equivalent to projecting a point on a complex manifold, which do not yield an analytical solution (except, again for some trivial cases). For neurons in succesions I am not even sure there is a geometrical interpretation.